# How to fetch and display data from mssql database using react and express?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reactjs, express

So basicaly I have a mssql database with customers, project and task lists and I need to fetch and display the data in a table form using react and express.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVJ43.png

So far I managed to connect to my database using express and I can display that info in json format using express in backend but the next thing I have to do is to display it on the frondend using react.

So far my code in react looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

state = { users: [] }

componentDidMount() {
fetch('/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
}


render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <ul>
      {this.state.users.map(user =>
        <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

The error I'm getting in react and the compiled version:

> **Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0**

Ref: [React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzA4Z.png) and [complied version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6DXW.png)

So, how do I connect my backend with frontend using just these two frameworks ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Whatever `/users` is returning is not valid json. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what it is actually returning in the response body. Also add a `catch()` to the `fetch` to prevent the unhandled promise rejection error

Comment: @charlietfl actually it is a valid json. I'm trying to display just the customers with their id for now and it pops that error constantly whatever I try to do. I think the problem is I'm not displaying the user right

Comment: Can you show us what data is coming back from `/users`?